# Calculate total resistance given resistors adjacency list

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory

The problem I need to solve is calculate the total resistance of a circuit given a list of the connected resistor (adjacency list if it is considered a resistor as a node).

For example in the following circuit:

[image: Resistor example]

The list will look like:

```
R1 -> R2
R1 -> R3
R2 -> R4
R3 -> R4
```

Each resistor has an ID and the value of its resistance. The tuples of connections are stored in a structure with `getFrom` and `getTo` methods.

The recursive algorithm I develop so far consider the calcutation of the total resitance between 2 any resistors:

```
private double calculateResistance(Resistor c1, Resistor c2){
    double res = 0;
    for(ComponentConnection cc : getGraph()){
        if(cc.getFrom().getId() == c1.getId()){
            if(cc.getTo().getId() == c2.getId())
                return c1.getRes() + c2.getRes();
            res += (1/calculateResistance(cc.getTo(),c2));
        }
    }
    return c1.getRes() + 1/res;
}
```

The problem is that when there is a fork in the circuit the algorithm cannot determine when it finishes and duplicates some componentes (in the example R4 is considered twice).

Any ideas how to fix this or solve the problem with another approach?

Comment: Is this really _only_ about the algorithm? Have you thought about all the weird cases like R1->R2, R2->R3, R3->R4, R4->R1? I think this is way harder than your simle example suggests.

Comment: There is a previous step where it is decided if a circuit is valid or not, this function will be used only for valid circuits then it is not necesary to worry about these cases.

Comment: Ah ok. What about R1->R2,R3,R4->R5? Or R1->R2+R3,R4+R5->R6?

Comment: I'm not sure you're approaching this correctly.  It's possible to calculate the resistance between any 2 nodes, where a node is a (non-resistor) point in the circuit.  Calculating the resistance _between_ two resistors doesn't make sense (unless you mean to be inclusive).  Calculating the resistance _over_ two resistors does...

Comment: I doubt this is recursive in nature. You have to successively reduce parallel resistors to their equivalent value, and series resistors to their sum, until there is only one resistor left. It is iterative until closure, not recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by recursively reducing **nodes**, not **resistors**:

- Start with the first and last nodes
- Are there intermediate nodes?
- No -> You're done.  Return the resistance of the (one or none) intermediate resistor
- Yes, there are intermediate nodes -> Reduce by recursively reducing for intermediate  series/parallel nodes.

Define reduce functions for the simplest series / parallel nodes (2 parallel and 2 series).  All others will eventually reduce to these.

Answer (score 0):

there are two operation for you to consider:

- reduce parallel resistors
- reduce serial resistors

for parallel resistors you have to consider **resistors**:

if two resistor share a connection on one side and share another connection on the other side you can reduce them

for serial resistors you have to consider **nodes**:

if a node has only two resisotors connected you can reduce them

the algorith would be:

```
boolean isStillWorking = true;
do{
    boolean foundParallel = reduceParallel();
    boolean foundSerial = reduceSerial();
    isStillWorking = foundParallel | foundSerial;
}while(isStillWorking);
```

Comment: yes, it's not recursive... it's very flat so even a noob as i are can handle complexity ^^